# [An error has been caught in function 'dia', process 'MainProcess' (1083395), thread 'MainThread' (139682043844416)]

Tags: python-3.x

I'm running this [code](https://github.com/antx-code/CVE-2022-22536/blob/main/CVE-2022-22536.py) as `python3 CVE-2022-22536.py` and getting the below error.
But I can't identify the wrong I'm done.
Please help me find out and solution to this.

This code is for testing `memory pipes desynchronization vulnerability` which is a request smuggling vulnerability tester.

And I add the host and port in the code section `poc()`

```
 poc = POC()
    host = 'aesg2-qe8-erp.aesg.accenture.com'
    port = 443
    poc.dia(host, port, secure=True, cert_verify=False)
```

The error will find [here](https://pastecode.io/s/2c9o6902)

Thank you very much.